# Why index scan instead of seek while using comparison operator

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, query-optimization, query-planner

There is a table `Sales.SalesOrderDetail` in database `AdventureWorks2014`.

I have two queries:

```
--Query 1 uses index IX_SalesOrderDetail_ProductID
SELECT
sod.SalesOrderID
FROM Sales.SalesOrderDetail sod
WHERE sod.SalesOrderID = 1
```

and:

```
--Query 2 uses index PK_SalesOrderDetail_SalesOrderID_SalesOrderDetailID
SELECT
sod.SalesOrderID
FROM Sales.SalesOrderDetail sod
WHERE sod.SalesOrderID > 1
```

Query plan:
[image]

[The query plan at Brentozar.com can be seen here.](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=rkjpNB33m)

And indexes:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_SalesOrderDetail_ProductID] ON [Sales]. 
[SalesOrderDetail]
(
    [ProductID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, 
    DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
    ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
```

and clustered index looks like this:

```
ALTER TABLE [Sales].[SalesOrderDetail] ADD  CONSTRAINT 
[PK_SalesOrderDetail_SalesOrderID_SalesOrderDetailID] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [SalesOrderID] ASC,
    [SalesOrderDetailID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, 
IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
    ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
```

My question is why does query optimizer prefer another index 
`PK_SalesOrderDetail_SalesOrderID_SalesOrderDetailID`
instead of `IX_SalesOrderDetail_ProductID`?

Comment: probably there is another index interfering with the clustered index. Check the indexes, disable any index that uses `SalesOrderID`, just leave the clustered index. and try to update statistics. Then check again.

Comment: @iSR5 how is it possible to update statistics?

Comment: use `UPDATE STATISTICS Sales.SalesOrderDetail WITH FULLSCAN`

Comment: Actually your comments are backwards. The first query uses a non-clustered index scan, and the second query uses a clustered index seek.

Comment: Please see [paste the plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/instructions/) for a better way to include an execution plan in your question.

Comment: @HABO I've inserted a query plan https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=rkjpNB33m

Comment: @AaronBertrand I've inserted an actual execution plan  https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=rkjpNB33m . In my view, my comments are not backwards or did I misunderstand something?

Comment: Look at what you’re calling “query 1” and “query 2” - the order you’ve listed them, and the comments in the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I mean, you're selecting *all* the rows (except maybe one). There really is no difference between a seek and a scan here. SQL Server is choosing to perform a single scan of the skinniest index instead of doing 80,000 seeks (or however many orders are in the table).

A seek is not always the best choice, but this is a common misconception. In fact sometimes you absolutely *want* a scan.

- [Scans are better than seeks. Really.](http://blogs.lobsterpot.com.au/2014/03/12/scans-are-better-than-seeks-really/)
- [Why the SQL Server FORCESCAN hint exists](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3296/why-the-sql-server-forcescan-hint-exists/?utm_source=AaronBertrand)
- [Why isn't SQL Server using my non-clustered index and doing a clustered index scan?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/76505/1186)
- [T-SQL Tuesday #56 : SQL Server Assumptions](https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/t-sql-tuesday-56-sql-server-assumptions/) (see #2)
- [“Tipping point” posts by Kimberly Tripp](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/category/the-tipping-point/)

Comment: Am I correctly understood that `table scan` is better to see the whole table when I want to show the all rows of a table than `table seek`?

Comment: Yes, usually a seek won’t be good for that. SQL Server makes a decision based on number of rows / % of table or index, look up “tipping point in SQL Server.”

Comment: thank you for your answer, is there a way to see that `table scan` is better than `table seek`?

Comment: Well it’s an index scan not a table scan. But sure, use a FORCESEEK hint and compare the I/O and duration. For extra fun add more columns and even some columns that aren’t covered by the index.